# Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-10.10

In my SSH log

- /var/log/auth.log

I have the following error message

- **Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory**

Any suggestions regarding the cause and how to fix it?

Thanks, Udo

**Update:**

Running

- sudo update-locale

fixes the error in the log.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Ubuntu - [Bug #155794 on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/155794) covers this and recommends running [update-locale](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-locale.8.html). You might have to look up which parameters you want to use with that :)